# Building form sources after making a change

Tags: dpkg

I had built qemu from source package on Ubnutu 14.04.1 successfully.
I did it with:

```
apt-get build-dep qemu
apt-get source qemu
cd qemu-2.0.0+dfsg
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

It had built qemu successfully. Now, I want for debug purposes, to add printing of debug messages. So I added one line in a file, and then tried to build again with the same command: `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`. It then asked me to commit my changes, I did it (with `dpkg-source --commit`), and then ran again

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

The thing is that it now ran the whole process of build, which takes more than two hours! So it seems to me that I am doing something not correct. Is there a way to build again after making a change, without doing all the build process, but just building according to the change that was made?

Comment: Use ccache or something similar - http://frungy.org/debian/ccache-building-packages. People who intend to develop software work directly with the source instead of building packages for every iteration

Comment: muru - while this is true, if you want to test with a real environment, which is based on the packaged image, you better work with the image which is created by the package manager and not directly from source, especially with large projects, as you may loss some settings if building directly. What I am looking for is some workaround which will avoid the automatic rebuild when using the package manager build process with "dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "real" environment, nor what settings you lose that you couldn't set yourself.